# Excel vba Deleting a row if a cell contains a text throughout whole workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to rename all sheets in a workbook based on a reference cell as well as delete rows that contain "-" within column C throughout the whole workbook, but I can't figure out how to apply the code I found on this forum to an entire workbook (and not only one worksheet). Please help!

```
Sub Master()
Call RemoveRows()
Call RenameSheet()
End Sub

Sub RemoveRows()

Dim r As Integer   
For r = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count to 1 step -1
    If Cells(r, "C") = "-" Then           
        Sheet1.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete    
    End If
Next 

End Sub


Sub RenameSheet()

Dim rs As Worksheet

For Each rs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
rs.Name = rs.Range("C3")
Next rs

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all the worksheets in the workbook, like so:

```
For Each ws in Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
   RemoveRows(ws) 'for each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook, call RemoveRows to remove its rows
Next ws
---------------------------------------------
Sub RemoveRows(Worksheet ws)  

Dim r As Integer   
For r = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count to 1 step -1
    If Cells(r, "C") = "-" Then           
        ws.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete    
    End If
Next 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Master()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
        RemoveRowsWithDash ws
        RenameSheet ws
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub RemoveRowsWithDash(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim r As Long   
    For r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row to 1 step -1
        If ws.Cells(r, "C") = "-" Then           
            ws.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete    
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

Sub RenameSheet(ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Name = ws.Range("C3").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: This successfully deleted the rows throughout the workbook but only renamed the first worksheet and came up with a 400 error. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Which line was the error and what was the error message?  It's possible your values in C3 may not all be valid sheet names.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Master()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Call RenameSheet(ws)
        Call RemoveRows(ws)

    Next ws

End Sub

Sub RenameSheet(ws As Worksheet)

    With ws
        .Name = .Range("C3").Value
    End With

End Sub

Sub RemoveRows(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim Lastrow As Long, Position As Long, i As Long

    With ws

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = Lastrow To 1 Step -1

            Position = InStr(1, .Cells(i, "C").Value, "-")

            If Position > 0 Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Note**

In my opinion is better to:

- Check if cell value is not empty
- Check if the new sheet name is not already exist
- Check if the length of the new name because there is a limitation in the number of characters you could use for sheet name (max 31)
- Check the the new name does not include invalid characters (\,/,*,[,],:,?)